# Displaying pdf in django

Tags: jquery, django, pdf

I have a pdf file and want it to be shown at my website, I've seen that it can be dynamically generated with Reportlabs but I just want it to display the file I already have.
What is the best approach to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PDFs are static files, and thus have nothing to do with Django. Just create a link to the URL that serves the file.